# How ThreadPoolExecutor cleanup in gRPC server?

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

When create grpc server instance,

```
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
```

`ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown` is not called by `server.stop()` in grpc `1.25.x`.

I wonder developer have to shutdown manually or `ThreadPoolExecutor` is shutdown by something(?).

What is grace method to stop grpc server and ThreadPoolExecutor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The gRPC does not shut down ThreadPoolExecutors provided to servers. That is the responsibility of the user. You are free to, for example, use your provided thread pool for your own work as well as for gRPC method handlers, so the library would be overstepping its boundaries to do that for you.

Of course, you don't want to shut down your thread pool until you've shut down the server that's using it. For this purpose, you'll want to use the [Server.stop](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html?highlight=stop#grpc.Server.stop) method.